# Incorrect Output when converting TEXT to Date ('yyyy-mm-dd') format (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

After I use the following code to convert column 'birthdate' (table: animals) from CHAR to Date, dates with incorrect year are getting displayed.

This is how 'birthdate' looks like in char format:

- 01/18/2019
- 02/05/2005
- 05/06/2013
  ...

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE animals ALTER COLUMN birthdate TYPE DATE 
using to_date(birthdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Output I am getting is something like this:

- 0019-01-18
- 0005-02-05
- 0013-05-06
  ....

It should be:

- 2019-01-18
- 2005-02-05
- 2013-05-06
  ...

Seems like '2' is replaced by '0' in the yyyy part of the date. This is incorrect, any idea why is this happening? The format I want is 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the initial data type of `birthday` is text. In this case your format string `YYYY-MM-DD` does not match the format of data. It should be `MM/DD/YYYY`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE animals ALTER COLUMN birthdate TYPE DATE 
using to_date(birthdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Please note that once the type of `birthdate` is changed to `date` (or it is `date` and no `alter table` is needed at all) it has no format anymore. You can format or rather *present* it as you wish using `to_char`.

```sql
select to_char(birthdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for highlighting. I was inputting the format I wanted as output in the initial query when I should have instead put the format of the text date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast the column type to date. try below query.

```
ALTER TABLE animals ALTER birthdate type date
using      (birthdate::date)
```